# Jeval EvaluationException: Invalid use of quotes

Tags: single-quotes

When I try to evaluate an expression I get this error: net.sourceforge.jeval.EvaluationException: Invalid use of quotes.

To be clearer. I read my rules from a .txt files where after I put them in a hasmap.

I have tried:

```
#{mentor} = Chung
#{mentor} = "Chung"
#{mentor} == "Chung"
#{mentor} == 'Chung'
```

but still gives another error or same error.

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
List<String> approvalMentors = new ArrayList<>();
Evaluator evaluator = new Evaluator();
evaluator.putVariable("mentor", String.valueOf(graduationApprovalRequest.getMentor()));

for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : this.schoolRules.entrySet()) {
    try {
        if(evaluator.evaluate(entry.getValue()).equals("1.0")){
            approvalMentors.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    } catch (EvaluationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SchoolRules.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
return approvalMentors;
```

.txt File I read my rules from

```
#{mentor} = 'Chung'
```

Answer (score 0):

JEval internal validation logic assumes each "operand" (a part of the conditional expression) should be either a built-in function, a number, a special symbol, OR a quoted string. If there is even a single SPACE between the == and double-quote symbols, the check for correctness of quoted string fails. Each such operand should either begin AND end with a quote(s), or do not have the quote(s) at all. The latter is the case with numbers, for example.